# IntPtr.ToInt32() throws excption on 64bit, but will IntPtrToInt64() throw on 32bit machine?

Tags: c#, intptr

I have this code:

```
if (hnd == IntPtr.Zero || hnd.ToInt32() == -1)
```

`hnd` is an `IntPtr`

This throws `OverflowException`, so I modified it to

```
 if (hnd == IntPtr.Zero || hnd.ToInt64() == -1)
```

The documentation says ToInt32 can throw an exception, but ToInt64 can't(?).

```
  //
// Summary:
//     Converts the value of this instance to a 32-bit signed integer.
//
// Returns:
//     A 32-bit signed integer equal to the value of this instance.
//
// Exceptions:
//   T:System.OverflowException:
//     On a 64-bit platform, the value of this instance is too large or too small to
//     represent as a 32-bit signed integer.
[ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.Success)]
[SecuritySafeCritical]
[TargetedPatchingOptOut("Performance critical to inline across NGen image boundaries")]
public int ToInt32();
//
// Summary:
//     Converts the value of this instance to a 64-bit signed integer.
//
// Returns:
//     A 64-bit signed integer equal to the value of this instance.
[ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.Success)]
[SecuritySafeCritical]
[TargetedPatchingOptOut("Performance critical to inline across NGen image boundaries")]
public long ToInt64();
```

**So the questions:**
Will `hnd.ToInt64()` will throw an exception on a 32bit machine or won't?

Comment: is `-1` a *thing that you see?* would `static readonly IntPtr MinusOne = new IntPtr(-1);` - then comparing to `MinusOne` - work? You *might* need: `static readonly IntPtr MinusOne = IntPtr.Size == 4 ? new IntPtr(-1) : new IntPtr(-1L);`

Comment: @MarcGravell omg, that's also a good point, I will try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) states that:

> An instance of this type is expected to be 32-bits on 32-bit hardware and operating systems, and 64-bits on 64-bit hardware and operating systems

So:

- On a 64-bit OS, IntPtr can go from `Int64.MinValue` to `Int64.MaxValue`. Obviously, this can throw an overflow when converted to an `Int32` since the range is longer.
- On a 32-bit OS, IntPtr can go from `Int32.MinValue` to `Int32.MaxValue`, so you can convert that to `Int64` and `Int32` since the value will always be inside the range.